# Twitter Future & Cats Arrow

Tags: scala, scala-cats, twitter-finagle, cats-effect

I'm trying to combine **Twitter Future** with **Cats Kleisli and Arrow** and I have a compilation error that I don't know how to solve it.

The code is the following:

```
package com.example
import scala.language.higherKinds

import cats.arrow.Arrow
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data.{EitherT, Kleisli}
import com.twitter.util.Future

object ArrowApp extends App {

  type Resp[A] = EitherT[Future, Exception, A]
  type KleisliResp[A] = Kleisli[Resp, List[Int], A]

  val first: KleisliResp[Int] = Kleisli(_ => EitherT[Future, Exception, Int](Future.value(Right(1))))
  val second: KleisliResp[String] = Kleisli(_ => EitherT[Future, Exception, String](Future.value(Right("TEST"))))

  def combine[F[_, _] : Arrow, A, B, C](fab: F[A, B], fac: F[A, C]): F[A, (B, C)] = Arrow[F].lift((a: A) => (a, a)) >>> (fab *** fac)

  val firstAndSecond: KleisliResp[(Int, String)] = combine(first, second)
}
```

The error that I get it is:

```
Error:(20, 31) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type cats.arrow.Arrow[[A, B]cats.data.Kleisli[com.example.cats.ArrowApp.Resp,A,B]] 
val firstAndSecond: KleisliResp[(Int, String)] = combine(first, second)
```

If I replace the **Twitter Future** with **Scala Future** and I import the global executor **import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global** then code runs.

My **build.sbt** looks like:

```
organization := "com.example"
name := "scala-test"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.3"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.2.0",
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-free" % "1.2.0",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.1.0",
  "com.twitter" %% "finagle-core" % "18.3.0"
)
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Ypartial-unification")
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" %% "kind-projector" % "0.9.7")
```

Do you have any idea how to fix the compilation error?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need something like [catbird](https://github.com/travisbrown/catbird), because it

> [...] provides cats type class instances (and other useful cats-related stuff) for various Twitter Open Source Scala projects.
>
> It currently includes the following:
>
> - Type class instances for Future, Var, and Try (including Monad or MonadError, Semigroup, and equality)

Twitter's `Future` has nothing to do with scala's standard `Future`, and Cats does not provide any typeclasses for Twitter `Future`s by default.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Adding **catbird** to my project an importing **import io.catbird.util._** solved the compilation problem.